# What are the pitfalls of adding properties to a function object within the function?

Tags: javascript, persistence, state

I found I could use this technique to retain a sort of "state" within an event handler, w/o having to involve outside variables...

I find this technique to be very clever in leveraging the fact that functions are actually **objects** in and of themselves, but am worried I'm doing something that could have negative implications of some sort...

**Example...**

```
var element = document.getElementById('button');

element.onclick = function funcName() {
    // attaching properties to the internally named "funcName"
    funcName.count = funcName.count || 0;
    funcName.count++;

    if (self.count === 3) {
        // do something every third time
        alert("Third time's the charm!");
        //reset counter
        funcName.count = 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: So the question is - "What are the pitfalls of adding properties to a function object?"

Comment: thanks for the better wording...

Comment: Just keep in mind the variables will always be public - if the function can be executed, its properties can also be accessed.

Comment: I *think* IE has had issues with cleaning up those properties on functions. I believe there was a jQuery bug where jQuery was storing a reference to the bound element on the handler it creates internally, which caused a leak in IE when those elems were removed from the DOM. But if you're just storing a number, it shouldn't really be an issue even if it is leaky.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing that, you can use a closure:

```
element.onclick = (function() {
  var count = 0;
  return function(ev) {
    count++;
    if (count === 3) {
      alert("3");
      count = 0;
    }
  };
})();
```

That setup involves an anonymous function that the code immediately calls. That function has a local variable, "count", which will be preserved over the succession of event handler calls.

By the way, this:

```
var something = function dangerous() { ... };
```

is "dangerous" because some browsers (guess which, though Safari has had issues too) do weird things when you include a name on a function expression like that. [Kangax wrote the issue up quite thoroughly.](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/)

Comment: very cool, I like that much better than my `funcName.count = funcName.count || 0;`

Comment: Great!  Be careful **not** to re-declare "count" with `var` inside the handler function!